I would like to revert to the version of the whisperx model that I learned
When I run whisperx, it tells me that it is different from the version that once trained the model.
Also, I cannot install the old version.
This is my code
def use_whisperx(audio_file_name):
    device = "cuda"
    compute_type = "float16"
    # options = {
    #     "max_new_tokens": None,
    #     "clip_timestamps": None,
    #     "hallucination_silence_threshold": None,
    # }
    model = whisperx.load_model("large-v3", device, compute_type=compute_type)
    result = model.transcribe(audio_file_name, language="ja")
    model_a, metadata = whisperx.load_align_model(
        language_code=result["language"], device=device
    )
    result_aligned = whisperx.align(
        result["segments"],
        model_a,
        metadata,
        audio_file_name,
        device,
    )
    return result_aligned

This is an error code
The model was trained with pyannote.audio 0.0.1, yours is 3.1.1. Bad things might happen unless you revert pyannote.audio to 0.x.
The model was trained with torch 1.10.0+cu102, yours is 2.3.1+cpu. Bad things might happen unless you revert the torch to 1.x.

And when I tried to install the old version, I got the following
pip install pyannote.audio==0.0.1                                                       

INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of plan note-audio to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch-lightning<1.7,>=1.5.4 (from pyannote-audio) (from versions: 0.0.2, 0.2, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.4.1, 0.2.5, 0.2.5.1, 0.2.5.2, 0.2.6, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.4.1, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.6.1, 0.3.6.3, 0.3.6.4, 0.3.6.5, 0.3.6.6, 0.3.6.7, 0.3.6.8, 0.3.6.9, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.7, 0.4.8, 0.4.9, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.1.2, 0.5.1.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.2.1, 0.5.3, 0.5.3.1, 0.5.3.2, 0.5.3.3, 0.6.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.3, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.1, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.2.8, 1.2.9, 1.2.10, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0rc3, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.7.post0, 1.3.8, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0rc2, 1.8.0, 1.8.0.post1, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.3.post0, 1.8.3.post1, 1.8.3.post2, 1.8.4, 1.8.4.post0, 1.8.5, 1.8.5.post0, 1.8.6, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.1.post0, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.9.post0, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0, 2.2.0.post0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch-lightning<1.7,>=1.5.4


You can safely ignore the warnings you're seeing. According to a contributor from WhisperX:

"Warnings are completely fine and can be ignored. They are caused by the pyannote version WhisperX is using. These warnings were introduced in #210 and should not be the reason for any failure."

For more details, you can check the comment here.

Thanks your comment.
I checked the #210.
But if I ignore the error, program don't get subtitles.
Only finish program.
It doesn't make sense for a program to be unable to acquire subtitles!
